# Disabling weak protocols and ciphers in Centos with Apache

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, openssl, vulnerability, cipher

Can anyone help me determine hat could be the reason I am still getting VA gaps from scanner for the following? My server hosts multiple web app, but I am using the same settings for all virtual hosts.

**20007 - SSL Version 2 and 3 Protocol Detection**

***NOTE: SSLEngine and SSLHonorCipherOrder are both tuned on.***

This is for the protocols. All is disabled and only TLS versions 1.1 ans 1.2 are enabled, however, scanner still detects SSL v3

***SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2***

I have also tried this way:

**SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3**

I have tried testing the following:
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -ssl2 -> failure handshake (which is OK)
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -ssl3 -> this works, and not shure why because this has been disabled for all vHosts (settings is like the one above)

=====*=====*=====

The other 2 vulnerabilities:

**42873 - SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported**
Here is the list of medium strength SSL ciphers supported by the remote server :
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA Kx=DH Au=RSA Enc=3DES-CBC(168) Mac=SHA1 
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=3DES-CBC(168) Mac=SHA1 
DES-CBC3-SHA Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=3DES-CBC(168) Mac=SHA1

**65821 - SSL RC4 Cipher Suites Supported (Bar Mitzvah)**
List of RC4 cipher suites supported by the remote server :
ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=RC4(128) Mac=SHA1 
RC4-MD5 Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=RC4(128) Mac=MD5 
RC4-SHA Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=RC4(128) Mac=SHA1

This is the CipherSuite. I have marked bold all the ciphers found in the scanner, and all of them have been disabled on my config, however they still appear during scan:

SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 !EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !**EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA** **!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA** **!DES-CBC3-SHA** **!ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA** **!RC4-MD5** **!RC4-SHA**"

NOTE: Change log for the httpd version I have does not include the CVEs for the mentioned gaps as per checking. I am also aware that httpd needs to be restarted after each config change.

Please advise if any of you have suggestions, I might be missing something. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you restart apache after making the changes?

Comment: Edited my post. Yes you are correct, I restart apache after each change/config I tried.

Comment: What does your `SSLCipherSuite` line say?

Comment: Its the 3rd line on my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apologies for the trouble. My team mate has discovered the following lines should also be updated in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:

SSLProtocol -all -TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 -SSLv3

SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 !EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA !ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA !DES-CBC3-SHA !ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA !RC4-MD5 !RC4-SHA"

Once updated, it cleared the security scan result.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the apache doc, this is the correct documentation that will make A+ rating in apache centos server.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Refer the section "How can I create an SSL server which accepts strong encryption only?"

```
# "Modern" configuration, defined by the Mozilla Foundation's SSL Configuration
# Generator as of August 2016. This tool is available at
# https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
SSLProtocol         all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
# Many ciphers defined here require a modern version (1.0.1+) of OpenSSL. Some
# require OpenSSL 1.1.0, which as of this writing was in pre-release.
SSLCipherSuite      ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression      off
SSLSessionTickets   off
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Apache conf file, I use :-

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384:!DSS:!aNULL;
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

and this seems to avoid the necessity of specifying each cipher allowed, yet still gives the highest ciphers only.